# Что не так с объектной моделью в С++?

Tags: c++

Прочитал мнение Линуса Торвальдса о С++:

> ...And limiting your project to C means that people don’t screw that
>   up, and also means that you get a lot of programmers that do actually
>   understand low-level issues and don’t screw things up with any idiotic
>   “object model” crap.

Стало интересно, что не так с объектной моделью в С++?

Какие проблемы в С++ с объектной моделью?

Источник:http://harmful.cat-v.org/software/c++/linus

Comment: Вы спрашиваете о том, что не нравится цитируемому персонажу? Или вообще про проблемы со встроенной объектной моделью в С++ (кстати никто не запрещает использовать в С++ не встроенный объектный подход, причем в совместимой с С манере)? Или что не так с объектно-ориентированным программированием вообще? Было бы неплохо привести источник цитаты, а то как-то выдрано из контекста.

Comment: @VTT, UPD......

Comment: Я думаю  имеется ввиду, что  сама обьктная модель может быть далеко не идеальной не из за того, что идея плохая, а из за того,  что  ее создают,  сопровождают, пользуются много программистов, которые могут  и обложаться.

Comment: Это один из истеричных торвальдсовских rants аж из замшелого 2007 года. Ничего общего с реальностью высказанное там не имеет, не говоря уже о том, что подразумеваемым Торвальдсом различий в объектной модели С и С++ не существует и никогда не существовало. Это просто поток сознания, за который ему, надеюсь, самому сегодня стыдно (если, конечно, он чему-то научился с тех пор). Зачем это поднимать в 2018 году (!) - мне не понятно. Ни язык С, ни язык С++ далеко не является ассемблером - вот и все, что "не так" с их объектной моделью.

Comment: [Почитайте на досуге](http://harmful.cat-v.org/software/c++/) и обратите внимание на шутку (?) Дейкстры -- *`"C++ damages the brain … "`*

Comment: Месье Торвальдс вообще знаменит тем, что не стесняется в выражениях. :/ Чего стоит одно [*"I'm looking at the code generation and your compiler (GCC) is pure
and utter shit"*](http://lkml.iu.edu//hypermail/linux/kernel/1407.3/00650.html) (реакция на GCC 4.9, который просто так копировал константную переменную на стек)